# Sum of positive elements which consists signed single-byte elements

Tags: assembly

Find the sum of positive elements of the array M (N), which consists of signed single-byte elements, and write to the CX register. The starting address of the array is
7000: 0010H.

how can I highlight this, by what methods, etc. to write to the variable sum.

Comment: Please specify the architecture. "assembly" by itself is too broad if you seek a specific answer!

Answer (score 0):

The array contains both positive and negative numbers and you need to calculate the sum of all its positive numbers.

Next is what you'll need to program:

- Clear the result variable
- Load a pointer to the start of the array
- Load the counter with number of elements
- Top of the loop:

  - Load the element that the pointer points at
  - Test if the number is positive
  - Add to the result variable only if number is positive
  - Increment the pointer
  - Decrement the counter
  - Loop while counter non-zero